# determine whether a unicode character is fullwidth or halfwidth in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm writing a terminal (console) application that is supposed to wrap arbitrary unicode text.

Terminals are usually using a monospaced (fixed width) font, so to wrap a text, it's barely more than counting characters and watching whether a word fits into a line or not and act accordingly.

Problem is that there are fullwidth characters in the Unicode table that take up the width of 2 characters in a terminal.

Counting these would see 1 unicode character, but the printed character is 2 "normal" (halfwidth) characters wide, breaking the wrapping routine as it is not aware of chars that take up twice the width.

As an example, this is a fullwidth character (U+3004, the JIS symbol)

```
〄
12
```

It does not take up the full width of 2 characters here although it's preformatted, but it does use twice the width of a western character in a terminal.

To deal with this, I have to distinguish between fullwidth or halfwidth characters, but I cannot find a way to do so in C++. Is it really necessary to know all fullwidth characters in the unicode table to get around the problem?

Comment: Relevant http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a3376f0d34bb23c54671859f1978b4226 and http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/

Comment: For which OS/Platform?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. OS is Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure how terminals will handle super wide characters [like these](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2978/81481). Not on my Linux right now to test printing ௵  ﷽

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use ICU [`u_getIntPropertyValue`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a3376f0d34bb23c54671859f1978b4226) with the `UCHAR_EAST_ASIAN_WIDTH` property.

For example:

```
bool is_fullwidth(UChar32 c) {
    int width = u_getIntPropertyValue(c, UCHAR_EAST_ASIAN_WIDTH);
    return width == U_EA_FULLWIDTH || width == U_EA_WIDE;
}
```

Note that if your graphics library supports combining characters then you'll have to consider those as well when determining how many cells a sequence uses; for example `e` followed by `U+0301` COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT will only take up 1 cell.

Comment: I'm about to replace all calls to ICU right now to minimize dependencies. Maybe I can build a table of all fullwidth characters with the help of the u_getIntPropertyValue method. Thanks for the hint to the combining characters. I will check whether this applies to terminals, too.

Comment: @Noice It may no longer be relevant for you, but I've recently put together the character ranges for a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15651264/777186

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to build tables, people from Unicode have already done that:

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c

The same code is used in terminal emulating software such as `xterm`[[1]](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/), `konsole`[[2]](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/applications/konsole/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/konsole_wcwidth.cpp) and quite likely others...