# How to detect unicode string width in terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, utf-8, utf-32

I'm working on a terminal based program that has unicode support.   There are certain cases where I need to determine how many terminal columns a string will consume before I print it.  Unfortunately some characters are 2 columns wide (chinese, etc.), but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114470/804775) that indicates a good way to detect fullwidth characters is by calling u_getIntPropertyValue() from the ICU library.

Now I'm trying to parse the characters of my UTF8 string and pass them to this function.  The problem I'm having now is that u_getIntPropertyValue() expects a UTF-32 code point.

What is the best way to obtain this from a utf8 string?  I'm currently trying to do this with boost::locale (used elsewhere in my program), but I'm having trouble getting a clean conversion.  My UTF32 strings that come from boost::locale are pre-pended with a [zero-width character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) to indicate byte order.  Obviously I can just skip the first four bytes of the string, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Here is my current ugly solution:

```
inline size_t utf8PrintableSize(const std::string &str, std::locale loc)
{
    namespace ba = boost::locale::boundary;
    ba::ssegment_index map(ba::character, str.begin(), str.end(), loc);
    size_t widthCount = 0;
    for (ba::ssegment_index::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
    {
        ++widthCount;
        std::string utf32Char = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(it->str(), std::string("utf-32"));

        UChar32 utf32Codepoint = 0;
        memcpy(&utf32Codepoint, utf32Char.c_str()+4, sizeof(UChar32));

        int width = u_getIntPropertyValue(utf32Codepoint, UCHAR_EAST_ASIAN_WIDTH);
        if ((width == U_EA_FULLWIDTH) || (width == U_EA_WIDE))
        {
            ++widthCount;
        }

    }
    return widthCount;
}
```

Comment: If you already use ICU, why not use it for utf8-to-utf32 conversion too?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ICU.  I was trying to use boost::locale to insulate me from most of the complexity.  Is there an easy way to get this utf32 code point from ICU directly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it either but I know it has everything anyone ever wanted from a unicode library. Spend some time with google and you will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-32 is the direct representation of the "code points" of the individual characters. So all you need to do is extract those from the UTF-8 characters and feed this to `u_getIntPropertyValue`.

I took your code and modified it to use [u8_to_u32_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/internal_details/uni_iter.html), which seems to be made just for this:

```
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>

inline size_t utf8PrintableSize(const std::string &str, std::locale loc)
{
    size_t widthCount = 0;
    for(boost::u8_to_u32_iterator<std::string::iterator> it(input.begin()), end(input.end()); it!=end; ++it)
    {
        ++widthCount;

        int width = u_getIntPropertyValue(*it, UCHAR_EAST_ASIAN_WIDTH);
        if ((width == U_EA_FULLWIDTH) || (width == U_EA_WIDE))
        {
            ++widthCount;
        }

    }
    return widthCount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the boost implementation.  Interesting that this is part of the regex library and not locale.

Answer (score 2):

@n.m was correct: there is an easy way to do this with ICS directly.  Updated code is below.  I suspect I can probably just use UnicodeString and bypass the whole boost locale usage in this scenario.

```
inline size_t utf8PrintableSize(const std::string &str, std::locale loc)
{
    namespace ba = boost::locale::boundary;
    ba::ssegment_index map(ba::character, str.begin(), str.end(), loc);
    size_t widthCount = 0;
    for (ba::ssegment_index::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
    {
        ++widthCount;

        //Note: Some unicode characters are 'full width' and consume more than one
        // column on output.  We will increment widthCount one extra time for
        // these characters to ensure that space is properly allocated
        UnicodeString ucs = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(it->str()));
        UChar32 codePoint = ucs.char32At(0);

        int width = u_getIntPropertyValue(codePoint, UCHAR_EAST_ASIAN_WIDTH);
        if ((width == U_EA_FULLWIDTH) || (width == U_EA_WIDE))
        {
            ++widthCount;
        }

    }
    return widthCount;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to handle zero-width characters too!

Comment: @o11c do you know how to check for this?  I'm turning up blanks with my probably-misguided google search.

Comment: Something like `General_Category in {"Mn", "Me"} or Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` - the latter includes formatting characters, soft hyphen, etc. But then, you also have to do even more complex stuff for Hangul combining, which depends on what the preceding character was.